# Storing configuration object in Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was wondering if it would be acceptable to store a configuration object, as well as several other objects that my React/Redux application requires in the store/state? These are common objects that all components need access to.

I was thinking they could be added to the initial state when the store is created, that way all components for example would have access to these objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally find the redux store be a very useful location to keep configuration as it is easily available in all the places I usually need it (components, thunks, sagas, etc.)

If you are using `combineReducers` you will get a warning if you have any keys in the `initialState` without a matching reducer.

A simple work around for this is to create a reducer with the sole purpose of providing the configuration in the state:

```
export default (state = { ...configuration }) => state
```

This can them be combined with all your other reducers like normal.

**Note:**  The reason I spread the `configuration` object into the `state` param is so the it is guaranteed to be immutable in the store.  If you are more confident that the `configuration` object wont mutate in you app, this can be simplified to:

```
export default () => configuration
```

Comment: Thanks, makes lots of sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a matter of opinion, but the redux store is a good place to store dynamic stuff you need access to globally, and then you can just map the relevant pieces to props as and when you need them in each component.